# Как преобразовать json файл с cookies чтобы использовать их в php cURL?

Tags: php, curl, cookie, puppeteer

Через **puppeteer** я получаю куки сайта:

```
const cookies = await page.cookies();
```

Они имеют такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно в дальнейшем передавать эти куки через cURL в php:

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt'
```

Как преобразовать json с куками от puppeteer которые бы работали если передать их в php cURL?

Comment: спарсь куки curl'ом и посмотри в каком формате они там лежат, в таком формате и сохранишь файл для дальнейшего использования

Comment: а вообще каждая кука на новой строке, данные через пробел в таком формате https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html